# How to finish Activity in flow, Flow Control

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Now I have `HomeActivity` -> `Activity A` -> `Activity B` -> `Activity C`

After I finish Activity C I expect to see `HomeActivity`. How can I handle this flow with Intent Flags or any other suggestions?

**edit**

But `Activity A` and `Activity B` should be removed from the stack when `Activity C` appear.

`Activity A` `B` and `C` this a workflow, So `A` can go to `B` and `B` can go back to `A` to edit something, After I Submit in `B` then `A` and `B` should be gone and show `C` as a confirmation

Comment: your can send broadcast to activity A,B to finish themselves.

Comment: When User in Activity B then user press back it's should show Activity A. In term to clear stack should clear when Activity C Appear

Comment: yes you have to send broadcast from C if user click backpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using launch modes you can achieve this.
use Single Task for the Activity C in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityC"
 android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

- [**`setFlags(...)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
- [**`finish();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

**Code Structure**

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Comment: @theerasantonthongkam Solved this yet?

Comment: I use send result to previous activity and let it finish when receive the finish result

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You should kill the activity before starting the next one.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, HomeActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```